# Slide jumping within equation environment

Tags: beamer, equations

I was wondering if there was an easy way to jump slides within an equation by clicking on a math value. Also how I can make the link font such that it is less obvious that it is a link. For example, how can I make this compile and give me the result that I want?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Hello World!}
\hyperlink{Goodbye!}{\beamerbutton{Go back to previous hyperlink}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Goodbye!}
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{22}{7} = \hyperlink{Hello World!}{\beamerbutton{\Pi}}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to "give [you] the result that [you] want", as you don't tell exactly what you want. But here are two possibilities:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Hello World!}
\hyperlink{Goodbye!}{\beamerbutton{Go back to previous hyperlink}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Goodbye!}
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{22}{7} = \hyperlink{Hello World!}{\Pi}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you want to keep the button (the numbers are just guessed by eye)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Hello World!}
\hyperlink{Goodbye!}{\beamerbutton{Go back to previous hyperlink}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Goodbye!}
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{22}{7} = \raisebox{-.3\baselineskip}{\scalebox{1.8}{\hyperlink{Hello World!}{\beamerbutton{$\Pi$}}}}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I were to click Pi, would that take me to the Hello World! frame?

Comment: @JoshEubanks yes, try it!